# Should I use Redux for user profiles?

Tags: reactjs, redux

My app makes a get request when the user navigates to a profile page, and there are params in the url to request the data. Should this data be stored in Redux, or is it better to make the request within the component and save it in React state? I am generally not persisting the data anywhere else in the app once a user has viewed the page.

Comment: You can keep this in your separate component if other components don't need to interact with it. On a side note, this isn't the best kind of question for Stack overflow because it's opinion based and is too specific to your project for anyone to give a decisive answer.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I appreciate your feedback. Sorry, first time posting and couldn't find anything online about best practices so I'll bear your feedback in mind next time. Thanks

Comment: something to read when you're bored: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think you don't need to store them in redux as long as you can get the value anytime.